# How to pass arguments to a function from a wrapper function in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This question is not for asking why arrow functions don't have argument object. I'm happy to use non arrow functions as well. All I want to do is a wrapper function that can pass parameters/arguments to the real function. The example below just happens to use arrow functions. JUST EXAMPLES.

I have a class User which has a number of methods. Before calling these methods, I want to do a check. If it fails, it throws an error. How to pass the arguments to the real methods.

```
User._checkAndAction = (fn) => {
    return () => {
        let args = arguments;
        if (aSeriousCheck) {
            throw new UserError();
        } else { 
            return fn.apply(User, args);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This gets the user id
 */
User.get = User._checkAndAction((value) => {
    return value;
});
```

When I call User.get('a parameter'), the parameter is not passed to the real method (value) => value.

Comment: Arrow functions don't have their own `arguments` object.

Comment: If you use arrow functions, then you can also use the rest operator `return (...args) => {`

Comment: Thomas. You are right. I just tried and it worked. Thanks